# Could not load file System.Drawing.Common but it is not part of my references

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, devexpress

Since English is not my native language I'm gonna try to explain myself as clearly as possible.

I have an old project on Visual Basic targeting the .NET Framework version 4.5.2, the project has a reference to System.Drawing dll but no System.Drawing.Common dll reference, when executing the application on my development PC it works fine.

My problem is that when I execute it in a virtual machine that I'm starting to use by requirement of my boss that had no .NET installed, the application cannot found a reference to System.Drawing.Common dll; I already have installed on the virtual machine:

- .NET Compact Framework 2.0 (Since my boss told me that it could be some even older dlls)
- .NET Compact Framework 3.5 (Since it went with the 2.0 version)
- Windows Desktop Runtime 3.0.3 (Cause I found some links that said the dll is part of .NET Core)
- Windows Desktop Runtime 3.1.3 (Just in case)

And trying to install any of the .NET 4.x versions tells me that its already installed cause the OS is Windows 10.

Since that seemed not to work I also put a copy of System.Drawing.Common.dll directly in the executable directory and modified the project to load it when the AssemblyResolve event fires. But it still not working, and also I can´t understand why is it requesting that assembly if none of my dlls and exe reference to it.

I'm trying to keep the virtual machine with no developer tools so i'm not sure what else to do. Would be pretty grateful if anyone has some clue of what my problem is. Thank you.

Edit: what makes more noise in my mind is: If System.Drawing.Common is a dll of .NET, shouldn't it be automatically loaded to any .NET application when it is needed? or at least be recovered since I already put the dll in the same folder as the .exe file of my application

Comment: In .NET whenever you get this error message, it normally includes "...or one of its dependencies". Don't ignore this! Dependencies between .NET assemblies  is key to solving this and you need to analyze your code properly to identify the dependencies. Note: this is also exactly the reason it is requesting that assembly in the first place although you don't reference it. It is itself a dependency of something you are referencing. There is no one simple answer to this issue. Check out Fusion log viewer and get to know your dependencies.

Comment: Have you checked the `.config` file for any inconsistent `<bindingRedirect/>` entries?

Comment: There are a few things you can do 1) From Solution Explorer look at References and see if System.Drawing is in the list of References 2) Open the csproj file for the project with notepad and see if System.Drawing is in the file 3) Do a clean build    The System.Drawing may be in one of the object files and clean build will force all object to be recompiled. 4) Check the bin folder for dll files.  There may be a dll that is using System.Drawing.

Comment: @RegEdit actually tought about a third party dll using it, but discarded it since putting the dll file in the execution path didn't work and tried to see what assembly files where loaded in the AppDomain with the debugger on my PC but it wasn´t in the CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() list. It´s kinda hard for me to understand what you mean by identify my dependencies, actually I just started to work with deployment, never got experience making applications work on non-development PCs, so I dont know wich libraries I can rely on user's PC

Comment: @jdweng if you mean app.config yes, it has just references to DevExpress libraries, also unloaded the project and checked the project file to prevent any reference to System.Drawing.Common that solution explorer may have hide, but there was none

Comment: Publish the application which create a folder with setup.exe in root like any commercial software.  Then run the setup.exe.   This should install any missing dlls.

Comment: Soonnk you say `It´s kinda hard for me to understand what you mean by identify my dependencies` - of course, that's why I said check out Fusion log viewer.

Comment: @RegEdit Tried to read about it (actually didn't knew about that tool) but isn't it a developer tool?, I mean, I can my application with no problem on the PC but the virtual machine gets the error, is there a way to make the console run on the virtual machine?

Comment: @jdweng next time I got the opportunity I'll try that, I have no knowledge about anything but coding so it's going to be useful I guess